# having some confusion about c pointer assignment

Tags: c, pointers, struct, variable-assignment, dereference

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around pointer assignments in C. The asterisk character appears in many different locations and I don't understand why I would choose to use one way over the other.

Specifically in the code below:

why would I choose:

```
conn->db->rows = (struct Address**)malloc(sizeof(struct Address *) * conn->db->MAX_ROWS);
```

over:

```
conn->db->rows = (struct **Address)malloc(sizeof(struct Address *) * conn->db->MAX_ROWS);
```

and within sizeof, what does the asterisk indicate?

This is the origin of the code above. Not the entire program.

```
struct Address {
  int id;
  int set;
  char *name;
  char *email;
};

struct Database {
  int MAX_DATA;
  int MAX_ROWS;
  struct Address **rows; // USE ARRAY OF POINTERS
};

struct Connection {
  FILE *file;
  struct Database *db;
};

void die(const char *message) {
  if(errno) {
    perror(message);
  } else {
    printf("ERROR: %s\n", message);
  }

  exit(1);
}

void Address_print(struct Address *addr) {
  printf("%d %s %s\n", addr->id, addr->name, addr->email);
}

void Database_load(struct Connection *conn) {
  size_t i=0;

  // Each database will have two `int` values. read
  // those first.
  assert(conn->db && conn->file);
  if (!(conn->db && conn->file))
      die("Database load : Invalid Connection info");
  if (fread(&conn->db->MAX_DATA, sizeof(conn->db->MAX_DATA), 1, conn->file) != 1)
      die("Database load : Couldn't read MAX_DATA");
  if (fread(&conn->db->MAX_ROWS, sizeof(conn->db->MAX_ROWS), 1, conn->file) != 1)
      die("Database load : Couldn't read MAX_ROWS");
  conn->db->rows = (struct Address**)malloc(sizeof(struct Address *) * conn->db->MAX_ROWS);

  assert(conn->db->rows);
  if (!(conn->db->rows)) {
    die("Database_load : Could not MAX_ROWS Address  structures");
  }
```

Comment: `struct **Address` is not valid syntax. In a type specifier, `*` goes after the type name to indicate that you're specifying a pointer to the type. `struct` is not a type, but `struct Address` is.

Comment: The asterisk in `sizeof` indicates that you want the size of a pointer. Without the asterisk, `sizeof` would return the size of the structure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [dont cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @dablyputs Before asking your qustion you should at least check whether this record  struct **Address compiles.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow why? You (or someone else) will do it for him.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I know it doesn't compile but I didn't understand why. I'm a beginner at C and I am struggling with this section of Learn C The Hard Way. The code sample this is from is a solution to a problem in the book written by someone other than the author but it is using techniques that are beyond what has been covered so far. There is no way I would have known to search the topic of type casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`struct **Address` is illegal syntax. The base type is `struct Address` and there should be nothing but whitespace (comments count as whitespace) between the `struct` keyword and the *tag*, `Address`.

`struct Address *` is a type that is a pointer to a `struct Address`.

`struct Address **` is a type that is a pointer to a pointer to a `struct Address`.

---

A `sizeof` expression determines the size of a type in bytes. There are two forms:

- `sizeof(`*type*`)` (for some type, *type*) specifies the type directly.
- `sizeof` *expression* (for some expression, *expression*) uses the resulting type of *expression* without evaluating *expression*.

In the case of `sizeof(struct Address *)`, the first form is used. This is evaluated as the size of the `struct Address *` type (pointer to `struct Address`) in bytes.

In the statement:

```
conn->db->rows = (struct Address**)malloc(sizeof(struct Address *) * conn->db->MAX_ROWS);
```

the result of the call to `malloc` is a generic pointer type, `void *` and it is being cast to the `struct Address**` type by the *cast* operator `(struct Address**)` to match the type of the `rows` member being assigned to.

In C, it is actually the usual practice to omit the cast when assigning a `void *` value to something of another object pointer type, or vice versa. The statement can be rewritten, omitting the cast, as:

```
conn->db->rows = malloc(sizeof(struct Address *) * conn->db->MAX_ROWS);
```

Additionally, the *type* operand of `sizeof(`*type*`)` can be replaced with an expression that has the same type. Since `conn->db->rows` has type `struct Address**`, then `*conn->db->rows` or `conn->db->rows[0]` will have type `struct Address *`. Either of those could be substituted into the statement, rewriting it as, for example:

```
conn->db->rows = malloc(sizeof(*conn->db->rows) * conn->db->MAX_ROWS);
```

That can be less error-prone than specifying the type directly in the `sizeof` expression, and is common practice.